# Select except some columns in laravel eloquent when i use from "with" in join queries

Tags: join, select, eloquent

I use from "with" in join eloquent in laravel and I want to use select in get results of my query but returns error because for example i use with(['user]) and user is my model's name not tables name(table's name is users)
is there any way that i use 'select' with my model's name?
or i use except that get all of the default columns except specific columns?

thanks

here is my query:

```
AlbumGalleryManagement::with('image','user')
        ->whereHas('organization', function ($q2) use ($organizationSlug){
            $q2->where('organization_slug', $organizationSlug);
        })
        ->join('province_approves','province_approves.approved_id','album_gallery_managements.id')
        ->where('province_approves.approved_type',self::ALBUMMODEL)
        ->where('published_at','<=',$nowDate)
        ->orderBy('published_at','DESC')
        ->orderBy('album_gallery_managements.id','DESC')
        ->paginate(self::PAGINATE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use select() to get the specified columns. 
In using "with" in join; the columns result get in relations tag and i use them easily.

my last query :

```
      AlbumGalleryManagement::with('image')
        ->whereHas('organization', function ($q2) use ($organizationSlug){
            $q2->where('organization_slug', $organizationSlug);
        })
        ->selectRaw('album_gallery_managements.*')
        ->join('province_approves','province_approves.approved_id','album_gallery_managements.id')
        ->where('province_approves.approved_type',self::ALBUMMODEL)
        ->where('province_approves.status_type',config('constants.status_type.approved'))
        ->where('published_at','<=',$nowDate)
        ->orderBy('published_at','DESC')
        ->orderBy('album_gallery_managements.id','DESC')
        ->paginate(self::PAGINATE);
```